# Imprecision in float integers in C

Tags: c, floating-point, double, precision

There is some kind on imprecision when it comes to printing out of values of addition in decimals with many points of precision.

While printing out the values of addition of 2 floats till 17 digits of precision,
it leads to incorrect answer.

```
// Using floating point numbers,
// prove that 
// 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3

// BONUS POINTS if you use 17 digits of accuracy

// 3 failures accepted

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    float a, b, c;

    a = 0.1;
    b = 0.2;
    c = a + b;

    printf("%0.17f", c);

    return 0;
}
```

The result comes out to be, [Output of addition with float variable type] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/em7px.png)

even, if I use a double variable type,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    double a, b, c;

    a = 0.1;
    b = 0.2;
    c = a + b;

    printf("%0.17f", c);

    return 0;
}
```

The result comes out to be [Output of addition with double variable type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dzsc.png)

Comment: Do not put screenshot (as images). Just copy the output especially if it is text: it is much easier to read and to do comparisons. And if you need to include an image (usually when you have graphical outputs): include inline on the question, not as link. The better and quick to scan your question, more people will read and answer. Else we skip and check a better question on the huge list.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I think new users are not allowed to inline images. But I agree of course with not posting text as image: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Why does your title contain the word “integers”?